# Ubuntu 13.04 seems to randomly crash

Tags: ubuntu, kernel-panic

I'm using an x64 distro of Ubuntu 13.04 on a Dell inspiron 1464, but it keeps crashing for no apparent reason.
Took some pictures of the error screen (first picture is of one instance, the rest are from another single instance)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0ioM.jpg
I tried accessing the logs and the computer crashed again.
I have Windows 7 on a dual boot and there doesn't seem to be any issue with it.
How can I tell what the problem is? I want to know if this is a general issue or is it specific to me

Comment: You might be more likely to get an answer to this question if you ask it at [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: You need to get to the /var/log/kern.log to be able to find out what exactly causing this crash and then try to disable that particular device and then try to boot again to see if that fixes.

Comment: It seems argle-bargle to me, but after inspecting the kernel log as Salton suggested (thank you, sir), I noticed lines very similar to these just before the system crashed :
[ 1124.560208] type=1400 audit(1372790729.559:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=2123 comm="apparmor_parser"
Anyway, I switched back to version 16-ish of the kernel (the version the installation came with) instead of the latest one (25-ish?) and the system won't crash anymore. Thank you all for your replies.

Comment: Definitely specific to you. Does the crash always happen in the same place (`udp_queue_rcv_skb` at the top of the call trace)? Run a memory test: select “memory test” in the Ubuntu boot menu and let it run overnight.

Answer (score 1):

I can't view the image you posted above, but if it is a network-related one, I suppose the problem might comes with the wifi driver.

Dell Inspiron 1464 comes with a Broadcom wireless card, probably BCM4312, which has poor Linux driver support. I experienced similar kernel panic. My advice is to buy some other wireless card (such as Intel 5100 which I am using) to replace that.